# Next.js redirecting when there is a user not working in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm using next. J's middleware to redirect to the home page if there is no current user with next auth, now this works great in development and I get redirected just fine, the problem is when I deploy to vercel I get redirected to the home page even if I'm logged in, so there is supouse to be a current user, logged in or not i cant see the routes in the middleware file

This only happens in production when i deploy to vercel, it works fine in my local machine

this is the middleware.ts file

```
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';

    export const config = {
      matcher: ['/trips', '/reservations', '/properties', '/favorites'],
    };
```